# How to fuzzy match movie titles with difflib and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, difflib, fuzzywuzzy

I have 2 lists of potentially overlapping movie titles, but possibly written in a different form.
They are in 2 different dataframes from pandas. So I have tried to use the `map()` function with the `fuzzywuzzy` library like so:

```
df1.title.map(lambda x: process.extractOne(x, choices=df2.title, score_cutoff=95))
```

Which gives some good quality results. But the time complexity is such that I can only run it on a very small subset of both data frames. When I try incrementing the size of the data frames then it rapidly becomes unusable.

Then I tried to replace `fuzzywuzzy` with `difflib`. And it is much faster. But I can't get the results I want.

At first I tried:

```
df1.title.map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2.title, n=1)
```

And that was fast but the quality of the results was poor. Even missing some simple uppercase / lowercase changes. Playing with the `cutoff` did not help.

So I thought I was using the wrong tool. In the docs and examples I saw `get_close_matches` used on single words. In titles there are various words.

Is `SequenceMatcher` a better choice?

And if yes, then how do I fit it into the `map()` so it does the same as the aforementioned functions: return only the best result, and only if the result is above a certain ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a Python package which aims to solve this problem.  Amongst other things, it addresses the n^2 complexity of the problem (e.g. with two datasets of length 100, your code needs 10,000 comparisons).

You can install it using `pip install fuzzymatcher`

You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher) and docs [here](https://github.com/RobinL/fuzzymatcher/blob/master/examples.ipynb).

Basic usage:

Given two dataframes `df_left` and `df_right`, which you want to fuzzy join, you can write the following:

```
from fuzzymatcher import link_table, left join

# Columns to match on from df_left
left_on = ["fname", "mname", "lname",  "dob"]

# Columns to match on from df_right
right_on = ["name", "middlename", "surname", "date"]

# The link table potentially contains several matches for each record
fuzzymatcher.link_table(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on)
```

Or if you just want to link on the closest match:

```
fuzzymatcher.fuzzy_left_join(df_left, df_right, left_on, right_on)
```

Comment: Much needed package. But it requires "Visual C++ Build Tools" which is 4 Gb on HDD.

Comment: Interesting - I guess you're on Windows?  Do you already have pandas/numpy installed?  Could you provide details of where/when you get the error message?

Comment: I'm on Windows, pandas/numpy are installed. Installation attempt throws [error message](https://imgur.com/a/DXD5g)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise the Levenstein package needed that.  I've opened an issue to remind myself to get rid of that dependency in the next release.

Comment: Note: this is now fixed in the latest code on Github

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate the possibility of low-score matches as a result of case-differences, I'd suggest applying `.upper()` or `.lower()` to the columns you're matching.  After adjusting the case, you could compile a list of all titles into `ThisList` and apply the following function (relying, as you suggested, on `SequenceMatcher`) with a given `tolerance`.

```
def fuzzy_group_list_elements(ThisList,Tolerance):
    from difflib import SequenceMatcher
    Groups = {}
    TempList = ThisList.copy()
    for Elmt in TempList:
        if Elmt not in Groups.keys():
            Groups[Elmt] = []
        for OtherElmt in TempList:
            if SequenceMatcher(None,Elmt,OtherElmt).quick_ratio() > Tolerance:
                Groups[Elmt] = Groups[Elmt] + [OtherElmt]
                TempList.remove(OtherElmt)
    Groups[Elmt] = list(set(Groups[Elmt]))
    return dict((v,k) for k in Groups for v in Groups[k])
```

You can then apply the above function to the dataframe columns containing the movie titles:

```
Mapping = fuzzy_group_list_elements(ThisList,0.85)
df['Matched Title'] = df['Title'].replace(Mapping)
```